# Django query on related model

Tags: mysql, django

I have models like below

```
class Scheduler(models.Model):  
    id = <this is primary key>
    last_run = <referencing to id in RunLogs below>  

class RunLogs(models.Model):  
    id = <primary key>  
    scheduler = <referencing to id in Scheduler above>
    overall_status = <String>
```

Only when the `scheduler` reaches the scheduled time of the job, `RunLogs` entry is created.

Now I am querying on RunLogs to show running schedules as below.

```
current = RunLog.objects\
                     .filter(Q(overall_status__in = ("RUNNING", "ON-HOLD", "QUEUED") |
                             Q(scheduler__last_run__isnull = True))
```

The above query gives me all records with matching status from `RunLogs` but does not give me records from `Scheduler` with `last_run` `is null`.

I understand why the query is behaving so but is there a way to get records from `scheduler` also with `last_run is null`
?

Comment: You may have error in your syntax. Try with keyword argument like `Q(scheduler__last_run__isnull=True)`.

Comment: @Ivan corrected the query.

Comment: Is that `RunLogs` or `ResourceLog` ? This set aside, your query seems correct, and there's no way to test it without your data.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers corrected query

Comment: what kind of fields are `last_run` and `scheduler`? Are they `ForeignKey`? If so, why did you put one in each model instead of using `related_name`?

Comment: @masterfloda how the related name would have helped to fix this issue?

Comment: @Kishor Pawar, can you just run this query and show the output? current = RunLog.objects.filter(scheduler__last_run__isnull = True)

Comment: @AnushaPrasanth it will give you zero records as related queries by default do inner join.

Comment: Sorry @AnushaPrasanth not zero records, but all rows matching inner join, but no records with `last_run` are null.

Comment: @KishorPawar, Please add the real models.py data in the question

Comment: What do you want exactly? models? or data?

Comment: Need to see the models. Specify if the models are in different app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160901/discussion-between-kishor-pawar-and-anusha-prasanth).

Answer (score 1):

I just did the same steps which you followed and found the reason why you where getting all the records after running your query. Here is the exact steps and a solution for this.

### Steps

1. Created models

   ```
   from django.db import models

   class ResourceLog(models.Model):
       id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
       resource_mgmt = models.ForeignKey('ResourceMgmt', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
                                         related_name='cpe_log_resource_mgmt')
       overall_status = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True, null=True)


   class ResourceMgmt(models.Model):
       id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
       last_run = models.ForeignKey(ResourceLog, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
   ```
2. Added the data as following:

   resource_log

   ```
   +----+----------------+------------------+
   | id | overall_status | resource_mgmt_id |
   +----+----------------+------------------+
   |  1 | RUNNING        |                1 |
   |  2 | QUEUED         |                1 |
   |  3 | QUEUED         |                1 |
   +----+----------------+------------------+
   ```

   resource_mgmt

   ```
   +----+-------------+
   | id | last_run_id |
   +----+-------------+
   |  1 |        NULL |
   |  2 |        NULL |
   |  3 |        NULL |
   |  4 |           3 |
   +----+-------------+
   ```

   - > According to the above table resource_mgmt(4) is referring to resource_log(3). But thing to be noted is, resource_log(3) is not referring to resource_mgmt(4).
3. Ran the following command in python shell

   ```
   In [1]: resource_log1 = ResourceLog.objects.get(id=1)

   In [2]: resource_log.resource_mgmt
   Out[2]: <ResourceMgmt: ResourceMgmt object (1)>
   In [3]: resource_log1 = ResourceLog.objects.get(id=2)

   In [4]: resource_log.resource_mgmt
   Out[4]: <ResourceMgmt: ResourceMgmt object (1)
   In [5]: resource_log1 = ResourceLog.objects.get(id=3)

   In [6]: resource_log.resource_mgmt
   Out[6]: <ResourceMgmt: ResourceMgmt object (1)>
   ```

   from this we can understand that all the resource_log objects are referring to 1st object of resource_mgmt(ie, id=1).

   Q) Why all the objects are referring to 1st object in the resource_mgmt?

   - > resource_mgmt is a foreign key field which is not null. Its default value is 1. when you create a resource_log object, if you are not specifying resource_mgmt, it will add the default value there which is 1.
4. Run your query

   ```
   In [60]: ResourceLog.objects.filter(resource_mgmt__last_run__isnull = True)
   Out[60]: <QuerySet [<ResourceLog: ResourceLog object (1)>, <ResourceLog: ResourceLog object (2)>, <ResourceLog: ResourceLog object (3)>]>
   ```

   - > This query is returning all three ResourceLog objects because all three are referring to 1st resource_mgmt object which has its `is_null` value as `True`

### Solution

You actually want to check the reverse relationship.

We can achieve this using two queries:

```
rm_ids = ResourceMgmt.objects.exclude(last_run=None).values_list('last_run', flat=True)
current = ResourceLog.objects.filter(overall_status__in = ("RUNNING", "QUEUED")).exclude(id__in=rm)
```

The output is:

```
<QuerySet [<ResourceLog: ResourceLog object (1)>, <ResourceLog: ResourceLog object (2)>]>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Anusha for your efforts. I really appreciate it. The thing is I want records from both tables, I want all records where `resource_mgmt.id == resource_log.resource_mgmt_id`, additionally, there are records in `ResourceMgmt` for which there is no entry in `ResourceLog`.

Comment: @KishorPawar, The above query didn't work for you? what should be the output then?

Comment: In your query above, you already excluding `last_run=None`, I want them in output.

Comment: In short, I need outer join where I get matching rows from both the tables, and rows from `ResourceMgmt` where `last_run is null`.

Comment: In that way your query is working perfectly. but you need a reverse relation matching data. that is why we need to split the query like this. Did you try running this query which I mentioned in solution? Is the output wrong?

Comment: Its not giving me expected records Anusha. I tried just now.

Comment: Are my steps correct? if so what should be the output in the above case?

Comment: In your `Solution` You trying to include records which have `last_run` to set something and then you excluding those ids from `ResourceLog` query to get the records from `ResourceMgmt` where `last_run` is set to null. Right? But please understand, in my case, `last_run` is set to `ResourceLog.id` when `ResourceLog` id is created. As we are quering on `ResourceLog` we only get where `ResourceMgmt.last_run` is set to something and not getting records where `ResourceMgmt.last_run` is null, because there is no matching condition to get those records.